# How to make a list of IDs of a table so I cycle through the IDs and use in a different table

Tags: sql-server

I created a distance table/chart in the chart I want the ability to ada a city. 
I created a stored procedure in mssql which goes something like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sup_InsertCity
    
    (
    @cityName nvarChar(50)
    )
    
AS
    Insert into citiesTest (cityName)
    values (@cityName)
    

    declare @counter int
    declare @cityNumber int
    declare @cityID int
    SELECT @cityNumber = COUNT(idCities) FROM citiesTest 
    SELECT @cityID = @@Identity    
    set @counter = 0
    while @counter < @cityNumber
    begin
      set @counter = @counter + 1
     /*
     
     
     */
        insert into DistanceTest (CityTop, CityRight, Distance, time)
        values (@cityID, @counter, 0, 0)
        insert into DistanceTest (CityTop, CityRight, Distance, time)
        values ( @counter, @cityID, 0, 0)
    end

RETURN
```

Now the problem is that this would only work if one didn't delete city's making a gap in the cities id. Instead of doing a course I would like to go thrould a collection of the id's in the other table to assign as the second city.

Comment: Sorry for the bad grammar and ugly question I am using a dumb but useful iPad to type. I will clean the question when i am home. But maybe somebody can give me advise til then.

Comment: Your inserts are a bit strange - you are inserting the `@counter` and `@cityId` to `CityTop` and `CityRight` then inserting them again in a different order. Can you simply explain what your query is supposed to achieve?

Comment: Alan Oded, this distance chart displays the distance from two cities. When a new city is added one would need to insert the distances from both directions. Meaning from cityA to cityB and from cityB to cityA. That is why i have the two inserts.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I am going to try to use a cursor instead of a counter, I believe that is my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for you:

```
Declare @CityId int

Insert CitiesTest( cityName )
Values( @cityName )

Set @CityId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Insert DistanceTest( CityTop, CityRight, Distance, Time )
Select @CityId, CityId, 0, 0
From CitiesTest
Where CityId <> @CityId
Union All
Select CityId, @CityId, 0, 0
From CitiesTest
Where CityId <> @CityId
```

Comment: @Yaron Buki: This actually replaces all the code in your SP. The new `DistanceTest` records are inserted using a single `INSERT` instruction, which is much better than the loop you have used and you don't need to worry about the gaps between the city IDs.

Comment: This was a better script. It was only missing the the Insert to create cityA and cityB being the same city. Meaning the distance from Sacramento to Sacramento. I added an insert at the end which inserts @idCity, @idCity, 0, 0.

Comment: @Yaron Buki - If (@CityId, @CityId, 0 0) is a valid combination, then simply take out one of the Where clauses. There is no need for another insert.